# getting left space while dynamic added row in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding dynamic span with onclick .

```
 $.ajax({
                url:path,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false, // Not to process data
                data: formdata,
                success: function (result) {

                    if(result==1){

                        for (var FileName of formdata.entries())
                        {
                            var fileName=FileName[0].trim();

                            **$("#"+PreviewControl).append('<span onclick="showaleart("'+fileName+'")">'+fileName+'</span>');                                                  
                            $("#"+hdnHasFile+"").val(1)  ;**
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
function showaleart(filename){
alert(filename);
}
```

But when i click on that span element its giving error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
But if i replace onclick="showaleart("'+fileName+'")" to onclick="showaleart()" with out any argument.
It does not give error.and the click is working.
when i click on element and inspected the element . it was creating element like this.

```
<span onclick="showaleart(" bank.jpg")"="">Bank.jpg</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using quotations properly, the second set of `"` renders the `bank.jpg` outside of the onclick. You need to use different type of quotes and escape them. Try this instead:

```
'<span onclick="showaleart(\''+fileName+'\')">'+fileName+'</span>'
```

or

```
`<span onclick="showaleart('${fileName}')">${fileName}</span>`
```